# Sorting python list after template list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Just start with Python, i like it :)

But i have a small question.

I have 2 lists:

`list_a = ['XL', 'L', '0S', '1L', '1S', '2S', 'M', '58', '52', 'XXL']`

`list_b = ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', '0S', '1S', '2S', '3S']`

I want to sort "list_a" after the template list "list_b"

If it not exist in "list_b" i want to add it in the end.

The result i want is:

`['M', 'L', 'XL', '0S' ,'1S', '2S', "The rest unsorted here" ]`

Andreas H

Comment: I think it's usually good practice to attach the tag with the main language used in your question. The `python-3.x` is a nice-to-have, but too specific. To get some traffic, tag with `python`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes courses, First time here and i will remember this :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the second list into a dictionary that maps strings to their indices, then use `sorted` with this dict as `key`:

```
from sys import maxsize

list_a = ['XL', 'L', '0S', '1L', '1S', '2S', 'M', '58', '52', 'XXL']
list_b = ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', '0S', '1S', '2S', '3S']

bDict = dict(zip(list_b, range(len(list_b))))

aSorted = sorted(list_a, key=lambda x: bDict[x] if x in bDict else maxsize)

print(aSorted)
```

The `... else maxsize` part is the fallback for the case that the key is not in the dict. The `maxsize` is a very large system dependent integer value, which should be larger than the size of any list.

The output:

```
['M', 'L', 'XL', '0S', '1S', '2S', '1L', '58', '52', 'XXL']
```

Detailed explanation:

- `range(len(list_b))` generates indices `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]` of items
- `zip` creates list of pairs with items and indices: `[('S', 0), ('M', 1), ...]`
- `dict` converts to dictionary, so that you can now quickly find that index of `M` was `1`, for example
- The `lambda` is a function that takes a string, passes it into dict, and if it finds no index, returns `maxsize`
- Sorting by this key gives the result list.

The conversion of the list to a dictionary is necessary to ensure that the lookup takes (amortized) constant time, instead of linearly rescanning the list every time.

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(list_a, key=lambda x: list_b.index(x) if x in list_b else len(list_b))
```